# restAngular using method customPOST. text:[object%20Object] is getting added on to the end of URL

Tags: angularjs, restangular

The goal I'm trying to accomplish is doing a post in restAngular.    I keep trying the code below, but I receive a status code 400 with a customPost.  This is the URL I send my request to...http://localhost/api/api/index.php/auth/token/[object%20Object].  As you can see [object%20Object] is gettting added on.  How do I get rid of this?  Should I be doing another method besides a customPOST?  Why is this getting added on?

```
  var login = Restangular.one('auth/token').customPOST(
    {grant_type:"password", username:"b@t.com",password:"666666",scope:"app"},{},{},
    {Authorization:'Basic ' + client,
    ContentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second argument to [customPOST](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/blob/master/README.md#custom-methods) should be a string representing the path. Try this instead:

```js
var login = Restangular.one('auth/token').customPOST(
    {grant_type:'password', username:'b@t.com', password:'666666', scope:'app'},
    '',
    {},
    {
        Authorization:'Basic ' + client,
        ContentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
);
```

Or this:

```js
var login = Restangular.one('auth').customPOST(
    {grant_type:'password', username:'b@t.com', password:'666666', scope:'app'},
    'token',
    {},
    {
        Authorization:'Basic ' + client,
        ContentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
);
```

Comment: Still getting the 400 but at least we're one step closer. thank you.

Comment: I had to wrap the payload JSON in a call to JQuery's $.param({}) to parameterize it.  Once I did that, the 404 error went away.

Comment: If anyone finds it not working, i had to change `ContentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` to `'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`